# Why a new string I create in C has ╠ instead of blanks?

Tags: c

When I intialize a string:

char pol[100];

and printf it, I get this weird ╠ sign 100 times.
My question is how to intialize a string, print it and get only blanks?
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value

Comment: ╠ is 0xCC in codepage 437 which means [you've accessed uninitialized memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714). You can find tons of questions about ╠ and 0xCC here on SO. [printf displays "-858993460" or "╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠"; what are these?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51771240/995714), [Displaying this symbol ╠ instead of desired characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12905027/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
char pol[100]; 
pol[0] = '\0';
```

First characters will be a `null character`.

If you want all of your array: `char pol[100] = {0}`;

Test this way:

```
char test[100] = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    printf("%c ", test[i]);
```

You can see the assembly here:

For x86 old compilers, that will be generate like:

```
push    100  
push    0
lea     eax, DWORD PTR _teste$[ebp]
push    eax
call    _memset
add     esp, 12
```

On newer:

```
lea     rdx, [rbp-112]
mov     eax, 0
mov     ecx, 12
mov     rdi, rdx
rep stosq
mov     rdx, rdi
mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], eax
add     rdx, 4
```

Test it on [Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org) selecting apropriate compiler

Comment: `char pol[100] = {0}` initializes *all* elements of the array to 0

Comment: However, `char pol[100] = {1}` initializes the 1st element to 1, and the rest to 0. Keep that in mind.

Comment: please add the `;` after the declaration with initialization `char pol[100] = {0};`, thanks

Comment: _First character it's a null character._  What about all the rest of the characters?

Comment: Like @UnholySheep said, initialize all array with `0`.

Answer (score 3):

`╠` is a character with code `0xCC` in the OEM 850 codepage.

In debug builds, Visual C initializes uninitialized data with `0xCC` to help you detect uninitialized data.

You should initialize the array.

```
char pol[100] = {0};
```

or

```
char pol[100] = "test data";
```

Comment: Nothing to do with ASCII

Comment: wow thats some nit-picking. But ok, updated.

Comment: 437 is more likely, but I suppose that would be picky

Answer (score 2):

*When I intialize a string:*...

The variable `pol` has not been initialized, only declared, and as such, because of the definition of *[C string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)*, may or may not even be a `string` at this point. Using it in this state (eg. in a `printf()` statement) is dangerous as it can invoke *[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*.

Change this:

```
char pol[100];
```

to This

```
char pol[100] = {0};//initializes entire array to `0`.
```

or this for example:

```
char pol[100] = {"temporary"};//initializes to |t|e|m|p|o|r|a|r|y|0|?|?|?|?|
                              //which is a null terminated string
```